# Advanced formula in Excel / Adding text to a cell based on another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, automation

I am currently working on a project where I need to add a phrase to one cell based on a character referenced in another cell. For example:

[image: complete example snip]

As you can see, cell C1782 had "-pr" at the end and in cell E1782 the phrase "Platinum Reserve" was added mid text.

I am looking to automate this process but I cant seem to find a way to write this out in a formula.

I believe I will have to assign variables, as "PR"/"Platinum reserve" is only one example of added text that had to be done. I have about 5 other ones to assign, such as "-s" which would become "Silver"

I have a list with about 10.4k entries, so you can see why I want to build some kind of automation.

Comment: How do you know WHERE to add the phrase "platinum reserve" in column E? What does Column E look like prior to adding your phrase? You should probably leave column E alone and then add column F as your adjusted column. Also, since cell C1782 has both -S and -PR, then why aren't you adding "silver" to the adjusted title as well? What are the rules for adding your phrase and does the dash-suffix in column C always appear at the end?

Comment: "Platinum Reserve" would be added at the end of each cell, the reference I provide shows it kind of mid text but the end out be ideal. Colum E would be the same minus the "Platinum Reserve" text. As for the -s -pr rules, they would have their respective translations. All text in column C would end in the -suffix

Comment: Ok, but there were several other questions asked too, and nobody can help until we have a better idea of the rules.

Comment: Sorry, I sent my reply before I was done typing. So I made a edit. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of formulas to achieve this. I would leave column-E alone and add another column. This works assuming you want only one prefix added, which is based on the LAST prefix from column C.

Formula in Cell F2:

```
=IFERROR(CONCAT(E2,VLOOKUP(RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-SEARCH("#",SUBSTITUTE(C2,"-","#",LEN(C2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2,"-",""))))),$H$1:$I$5,2,FALSE)),E2)
```

Working inside out, it's doing this:

(1) This part identifies the text after the last hyphen:

```
RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-SEARCH("#",SUBSTITUTE(C2,"-","#",LEN(C2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2,"-",""))))
```

(2) Then that text is taken into a VLOOKUP formula against cell range H1:I5.

(3) Finally, if that text is not found, then the formula is wrapped with an IFERROR formula to prevent receiving an "N/A" value. If the IFERROR is triggered, then it simply returns the original title.

[image]

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much! instead putting "platinum reserve/silver/gold" at the end, is their a way to insert it in-between the end of the strain name and the word 'flower'?

Comment: Maybe. This leads to more questions. Can you further elaborate on columns C, D and E in your picture? How is E produced prior to wanting to add that "platinum reserve" description? That is, how do you know to add "flower" and "3.5g" while ignoring "Caviar" and other elements?

Comment: To further elaborate, it would probably help if I defined what it is a little better. C= an inventory name, its what the systems reads the item as. the purpose of using C is simply to grab the '-suffix' as it represents a specific text that needs to be added to column E.  We don't need to worry about Colum D as it's name is already present in E. Colum E is the online display name. This is what customers will see when shopping. The goal is to take that -sufx in C, translate it to its meaning (i.e. G = Gold) and add it into Colum E.

Comment: The goal is to take the translated -Suffix from C and insert it into the middle of the text in E. (well, not the exact middle just after the strain name But before the word 'flower' which is usually followed by a weight '1g,3.5g,7g' of which will already be in the text.